# 70 million rials in usurious money

Tags: vocabulary

In my country, usury is practiced by some people. For example, you ***borrow 70 million rials in usurious money*** from someone but you have to give him back 71 million rials after a week.

Does the highlighted part sound natural.

Answer (score 6):

It is the *act* of lending, or the interest rate which is [**usurious**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/usurious), not the money itself.

> **usurious** *adjective*
>
> Definition of usurious
>
> 1 : practicing usury
>   2 : involving usury : of the character of usury
>   // *usurious interest rates*

So no, "usurious money" does not seem a natural phrase to me. I suggest

> You borrow 70 million rials at a usurious interest rate, so you have to give him back 71 million rials after a week.

Comment: In English speaking countries, 'usurious' is usually used about money lending at an excessive, unfair, or greedy rate of interest. In Islam, all money lending for interest, at whatever rate, is called 'usury', and is usually banned.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to "sound natural," skip the word *usurious* altogether, and use *interest* instead:

> In my country, loans are paid back **with interest**. For example, you may borrow 70 million rials but you would pay back 71 million rials after a week; that is, you would pay back the entire principal plus one million rials **in interest**.

From NOAD:

> **principal** (*noun*) a sum of money lent or invested on which interest is paid
>
> **interest** (*noun*) money paid regularly at a particular rate for the use of money lent, or for delaying the repayment of a debt